# Has Max Brooks ever discussed the possibility of writing more zombie books?

Tags: zombie, authors, world-war-z

I know that he's now busy being the world's most respected zombie expert, and I seem to remember him saying that he had already told the full story of *World War Z* (and I personally don't see how anyone could write a sequel), but has Max Brooks ever said that he is writing/will eventually write/could conceivably write more books about zombies?

Comment: Note:  Before anyone tries to close this question under the "future works" policy, stop.  I'm not asking "what will Max Brooks' next book be like?", nor am I even asking if he'll ever write anything again.  I'm asking if he has ever *said* anything about it **in the past**.

Comment: Which is, of course perfectly well on topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Max Brooks has repeatedly denied that he's *currently* writing another Zombies book, stating that he's lost interest in the genre.

> Are you kidding? Everybody's still trying to get me to do Space Balls 2: The Search for More Money. To be honest, I'm a shitty businessman. If I were better, I'd be on World War Z Part 7. But **unfortunately, I have to write the things I'm obsessing about.** - [GQ](http://www.gq.com/story/max-brooks-interview-harlem-hellfighters-world-war-z)

That being said, he's not ruled it out for the future...

> **Any plans for a sequel [To World War Z]?**
>
> **Max Brooks:** *Maybe, I'll have to give it some time and see what germinates. It's always too tempting to rush to capitalize on the success of a previous work and I'm going to have to be VERY careful to make sure another zombie book doesn't suck.* - [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/discussion/2006/10/03/DI2006100300686.html)

The cynic in me says that as soon as he writes something that flops, he'll immediately put pen to paper on a new zombies novel.